# Laravel Dusk VueJS SPA router-view injected components

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-dusk

I use `<router-view>` to inject components based on the route. I want to make vue-assertions in Laravel Dusk now.

```html
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath" :dusk="$route.name"></router-view>
```

But when I do `->assertVue('field', 'value', '@indexOrder')` on my order index route, I get this error:

```
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnexpectedJavascriptException: javascript error: Cannot read property '__vue__' of null
```

Of course, I made sure that the route's name is `indexOrder` and is correctly put in the `dusk`-attribute of the `router-view` component. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

While this is not exactly an answer, it can help move you in the right direction.

When you run the following command in your browser console on the route you're testing, you'll see a `$children` variable.

```js
document.querySelector('body [dusk="YOUR_ROUTE_NAME"]').__vue__;
```

The above command is what Dusk executes in its `MakesAssertions` trait under the `vueAttribute` method. This `$children` variable holds all of your components loaded by the router, so you'll have to create some new methods and assertions to support vue-router in Dusk.

Comment: So, by default Laravel Dusk does not support `vue-router`?

Comment: That was the case when I last used it a few years ago. Perhaps it has changed with future iterations.